# Run Codeception acceptance tests against a self-signed ssl site

Tags: selenium, ssl, phantomjs, codeception, acceptance-testing

I have a website with a letsencrypt ssl cert. When I ran codeception acceptance tests against it, the test stalls until I press ctrl+z. When I ran the same test against a non ssl site, there is no problem.

That is my setup in acceptance.suite.yml. The phantomjs.cli.args paramater is from this site: http://szdredd.blogspot.de/2013/10/codeception-phantomjs-setup-for.html

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled: [WebDriver]
    config:
        WebDriver:
            url: https://www.domain.de/
            browser: phantomjs
```

My selenium log looks like this:

```
17:07:15.681 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{browserName=phantomjs}]])
17:07:15.682 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{browserName=phantomjs}]
17:07:15.682 INFO - executable: /usr/bin/phantomjs
17:07:15.683 INFO - port: 27757
17:07:15.683 INFO - arguments: [--webdriver=27757, --webdriver-logfile=/phantomjsdriver.log]
17:07:15.683 INFO - environment: {}
PhantomJS is launching GhostDriver...
[INFO  - 2016-02-20T17:07:15.754Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 27757
[INFO  - 2016-02-20T17:07:15.765Z] Session [64316920-d7f4-11e5-a0c5-8954be0ea076] - CONSTRUCTOR - Desired Capabilities: {"browserName":"phantomjs"}
[INFO  - 2016-02-20T17:07:15.765Z] Session [64316920-d7f4-11e5-a0c5-8954be0ea076] - CONSTRUCTOR - Negotiated Capabilities: {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"1.9.0","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.0.3","platform":"linux-unknown-64bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
[INFO  - 2016-02-20T17:07:15.765Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: 64316920-d7f4-11e5-a0c5-8954be0ea076
17:07:15.771 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{browserName=phantomjs}]]
17:07:15.774 INFO - Executing: [implicitly wait: 0])
17:07:15.777 INFO - Done: [implicitly wait: 0]
17:07:15.790 INFO - Executing: [get: https://www.waldhelden.de/])
[INFO  - 2016-02-20T17:07:33.916Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW
[INFO  - 2016-02-20T17:08:55.442Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW
```

[INFO  - 2016-02-20T17:09:02.008Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW
    17:09:13.204 INFO - Session 7c5ef02c-9361-49c8-894d-234989179189 deleted due to client timeout
    [INFO  - 2016-02-20T17:09:13.211Z] ShutdownReqHand - _handle - About to shutdown

I found an advise on this side, but when I add that configuration I an error:

```
capabilities:
    phantomjs.cli.args: ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true']

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The best matching driver provider org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver can't create a new driver instance for Capabilities [{phantomjs.cli.args=[--ignore-ssl-errors=true], browserName=phantom}]
```

Who knows how to setup codeception to ignore ssl errors? Any help appreciated!

Thanks 
Udo

Answer (score 0):

For testing my site I use Phantoman to automatically run and close `phantomJS`. In `codeception.yml` I have:

```
config:
    Codeception\Extension\Phantoman:
        path: 'vendor/bin/phantomjs'
        port: 4444
        debug: true
        ignoreSslErrors: true
        sslProtocol: any
    Codeception\Extension\Recorder:
        delete_successful: true
```